# Where to use Redux and sessionStorage?

Tags: redux, angular5, session-storage

I am developing an application in that i am using `sessionStorage`, I was reading an article and found that `redux` . After reading more about `redux`, I found that it is also used for state management ( currently i am managing my application state using `sessionStorage`) . Now I am confused where to use `sessionStorage` and `redux`.

Comment: check this out
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne yes it's a nice article and explain alot that it is good to adopt  `Redux`  but again my question is does i don't need to use `sessionStorage` where ever term comes of state manage use Redux or in actual hybrid approach is follow i.e. usage of both